# What does すまなく思うが mean?

Tags: meaning, renyōkei

すまなく is 'sorry' but how does 思うが change this meaning? 'I feel sorry?'

Comment: Your question was already answered here. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61261/what-is-the-meaning-of-%e3%81%86%e3%81%8c If you don't understand the answer then please edit that question.

Comment: But this is a different question and it wasn't answered

Comment: Your new question is based on the same error that was corrected in the previous question. If you fix that error, then you have no question. If I'm misunderstanding then please make the question clearer.

Comment: The answer was that the whole sentence  is すまなくお前うが and not just お前うが but what i want to know is what the うが is for

Comment: No. The answer was that お前うが is a typo and should read 思うが.　There is no うが. There is the verb 思う followed by が.

Comment: Let's leave the question open and about 連用形＋思うが since it's been answered and could be useful to future users.  The previous question was about the typo and has been answered, so let's leave that one closed and not edit it to be about something different.

Answer (score 3):

すまない = sorrowful

すまなく = sorrowfully (this is the 連用形 of すまない)

思う = to think (verb)

が = but (conjunctive)

Literally すまなく思うが = I think sorrowfully but... = I feel sorry but ...

The sentence is unfinished. It is up to the reader/listener to guess what follows.

Comment: 「連体形」?  Is that a typo or did you mean to say it?

Comment: @l'électeur I did mean to say it, but I'm guessing from your comment that I got it wrong. Could you please correct me? Thanks.

Comment: Ah just looked again. I think I meant this: 連用形

Comment: That's more like it.  Now +1.

Answer (score 0):

Here the meaning of 思う is ratherr "feel" than "think" in English.

すまなく思うが＝ Though I feel sorry,...